# Is this app a legitimate Stack Overflow app?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-app

***This is around 2 or 3 months ago.***

I came across a mobile app in PlayStore(with id `com.sanson.stackexchange`) for Stack Overflow which had a large number of bad reviews and most of them were claiming that the app is stealing passwords and doing nothing related to real Stack Overflow.

I think this app has been taken down as I can not find it anymore.

***This is today***

I came across a mobile application in PlayStore for Stack Overflow, but it does not look genuine to me. It is from a person called "Kella Mohan Sandeep Kumar" and only have three reviews.

[image]

[image]

Is this the genuine Stack Overflow mobile app for Android?

If not, is there something Stack Overflow or the community can do to preventing people creating apps using Stack Overflow name for their own personal gain?

<sub>I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If not, please let me know, and I will take it question down.</sub>

Comment: The only legit SO mobile app is EOL, unsupported and I (think) no longer available. What you have there is a genuine mobile app, just not one made by SO Inc.

Comment: Judging by the botched name I would say definitely not.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370587/349058

Comment: It's fake. Please report it.

Comment: “It really loved it” thats probably fake. Also kella mohan sandeep kumar is would not be the official authors name of the real app.

Comment: Well, they grossly misspelt [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) as "StackoverFlow" and somewhat less grossly misspelt it as "StackOverflow". Perhaps the unnatural spelling "Stack Overflow" is good for something after all.

Comment: And a ***third*** time as "stackoveflow", perhaps the [grossest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grossest) of all.

Comment: I just deleted my stack overflow mobile app and changed my password lol

Comment: *"1000+ installs"* - let us hope it is [mostly harmless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5P3lZu4xeI&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=7&t=6m39s) (like most poems). Perhaps they are taking advantage of the desperate need for a mobile app after it [was abandoned](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678) (as expressed in many [Über meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-app) posts)?

Comment: They should create dummy apps that redirect to the website until all mobile users get the message.

Comment: "They" / SO should not really need to do anything, of course legal can contact the google / play store, etc. But at the end of the day it up to the user to figure out what app they install, who programmed it and whether or not it is a remotely good idea to enter credentials into it. And this one is **obviously** not genuine, there is nothing that hints at it being genuine.

Comment: @luk2302 You misunderstand my meaning, I mean that the mobile version of the website is fine. Of course they, SO, do not have to do anything I say. I was humouristically suggesting, after Peter's comment that a mobile app was something that was asked for, and considering SO's position is "use the website", that a cool prank would be to create the app, and have it redirect to the website.

Comment: Generally, it would even be possible to make a genuine mobile app showing content from SO, since the content is kind of free. But not like this, obviously.

Comment: I don't understand why people expect there to be an app for a freaking website. IT'S A WEBSITE, we already have apps for those, they're called BROWSERS. I don't understand why we need to be actively policing common sense.

Comment: @IanKemp Why is there a Facebook or Instagram mobile app then with billions of installs (just checked)? They're just freaking websites after all. I see your point, but I think it might be a bit exaggerated.  There might be advantages of a mobile app.

Comment: @Trilarion like, not having to downgrade the UI for everyone not using mobile to make it usable for mobile

Comment: While this particular app looks like a scam, I don't see what's wrong with somebody publishing a Stack Overflow app.  Maybe some people like having an app for everything they use.  Just because it's not the official app made by Stack Exchange, Inc. doesn't necessarily mean it's bad.

Comment: Similar on MSE (in the same time frame): *[Malicious app that misuses Stack Overflow trademarks is up on the Google Play Store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370587/)*

Answer (score 42):

This is not an app developed by Stack Overflow. [The official guidance from Stack Overflow developers is this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/244695) (emphasis mine)

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). **We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.**

As [noted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370589/244695), there is a way for anyone with a Google account to report these to Google directly from within the Play Store app. Google has to be the one to remove it, so more reports from users should get it removed in short order (all the Trust and Safety team can do is report it to Google as well [and cross their fingers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370587/malicious-app-that-misuses-stack-overflow-trademarks-is-up-on-the-google-play-st#comment1238656_370602)). Understand that copycat apps like these run the gamut of bad behavior, from merely injecting ads for the authors on top of the website to [grabbing passwords and doing other malicious things](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/07/google-boots-google-play-apps-for-stealing-users-facebook-passwords/). If you have installed any apps like this, I would uninstall them immediately and change any passwords used on your device just to be safe.

Comment: I'm constantly critical of SO's business practices, so it's only fair to praise them when they do something right. Kudos for not contributing to the scourge of pointless apps that should have been mobile websites.

Comment: @TechInquisitor:  If you're referring to Stack Overflow developing an app, then 1) you mean "anymore" since they stopped developing it, and 2) it's a bit orthogonal to the discussion (they'd had copycat apps for ages even *while* the two of theirs were in development).

Comment: @Makoto Then even more praise for not falling victim to the sunk cost fallacy. They're setting a very good example for other companies to follow. (*cough*everybank*cough*) Designing a good mobile site means there's less incentive for anyone to create or seek out those copycat apps that may lead to security headaches.

Comment: For anyone unaware, there have been official StackOverflow and StackExchange (SE) apps in the past. I used the official SE app until recently (my phone ran out of space). If anyone is still using these, if they work on your device, I think that is fine. They're just not officially supported, should any issues arise.

Comment: Are third party apps illegal under SE TOS? What exactly would be the valid reason to report to Google?

Comment: [Stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app) has a list of third party apps.

Comment: @TheMaster It's not an SE TOS thing. It's a "You have no idea what that app is actually doing" thing. Which is [a major problem Google Play has](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/03/found-malicious-google-play-apps-with-1-7-million-downloads-many-by-children/). I reported it as a "copycat" app.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better @Machavity. In short: We are aware and we have done everything within our purview in regards to this app. To be abundantly clear, we are not affiliated with it, so please use caution.

Answer (score 10):

> Is this the genuine Stack Overflow mobile app for Android?

No, it is not an official app.

> If not, is there something Stack Overflow or the community can do to preventing people creating apps using Stack Overflow name for their own personal gain?

You can report it as a violation of [Google's policy on impersonation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374?hl=en):

> We don’t allow apps that mislead users by impersonating someone else (e.g. another developer, company or entity) or another app. Don’t imply that your app is related to or authorised by someone when it isn’t.  Be careful not to use app icons, descriptions, titles or in-app elements that could mislead users about your app’s relationship to someone else or another app.

You can report the violation using [this form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/takedown). I selected "other objection" and wrote: *The icon and title of the app are both likely to mislead users into thinking it is an official app when it is not.* The form asks for the app package name, which is `com.sanson.stackexchange` according to the question, and a screenshot (I used the image from the question). I don't know if there is any benefit in the app being reported multiple times, but it probably doesn't hurt.

Comment: I predict `whois` is about to get a bunch of lookups for `sanson.com` (which is naturally redacted). I do also wonder if domainabuse@tucows.com will get some complaints, too.